# Current Best converter from a Latex source to Keynote with many equations

Tags: equations, mac, slideshow, convert

I am lost in front of the large number of converters from PDF to Keynote or to PowerPoint.

I don't want to convert a PDF to Keynote but I would like simply find an application that converts, as pretty as possible, a Latex source to a Keynote presentation.

Ideally, if the Latex equations from Latex source could be generated also into the Keynote presentation, this would be great (I mean, I can modify easily the Latex equations once the Keynote presentation is generated).

I am opened also for non-free applications, provided the result is pretty.

Comment: This question will probably be closed for being off-topic, but I offer my thoughts anyway. Keynote doesn't implement "real" LaTeX. It doesn't provide support for packages or anything at all like that. Before I abandoned traditional presentation software, I would use LaTeXiT to create PDF images of equations using my existing Mac TeX distribution and insert them into my Keynote slides as images with no problems. If you want to make entire presentations using LaTeX, you can always use beamer, but I don't know of a conversion tool from LaTeX source to Keynote.

Comment: Can you provide more context, like: why do you need to convert them? how many presentations? how many slides each roughly? how much editing do you need to do after the conversion? does the latex source use beamer? thanks.

Comment: @jessexknight . How to manage the content of each slide with beamer ? Is there a slide for each section or subsection : how to deal with it in my Latex source ? Does pdflatex can automatically produce the slides with beamer ? if you had a good link/tutorial to give me or a simple example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc (https://pandoc.org/) is currently the best option for converting LaTeX to other formats. You could covert it to PowerPoint by installing Pandoc and typing in the command line `pandoc mydocument.tex -s -o mydocument.pptx`, replacing `mydocument.tex` with the name of the file. It doesn't work flawlessly, but nothing really does, as LaTeX is difficult to work with.

Comment: I tried pandoc but it gives pretty bad results, are there options to apply or other similar tools ? a conversion from Latex to Keynote is not possible ?